# After a :windo, how do I get the cursor back where it was?

Tags: vim

Seems that `:windo` leaves my cursor in the bottom window.

How can I get it to return to the window and cursor-position I was at before I ran `:windo`?

I thought `mZ`, then `` `Z `` would work.  But it just brings that file into the bottom window, instead of moving me back to where I was.

Running 7.3.462 on Win XP.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sehe's great suggestion led me to doing two mksessions, and diffing them.

If I do this before `:windo`

```
let saved_winnr = winnr()
```

And this after:

```
exec saved_winnr . 'wincmd w'
```

It gets me what I need.

Comment: This answers the problem also:  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Windo_and_restore_current_window

Answer (score 3):

You could save buffer and view:

```
let saved_bufnr = bufnr("%")
let saved_view  = winsaveview()
```

and use it to restore the exact position (after `argdo`, `bufo`, `windo`, `tabdo`, `global` or any combination of those)

```
exec 'buffer ' . saved_bufnr
call winrestview(saved_view)
```

**Note** This effectively uses the plumbing that underlies the standard `:mkview`, `:mksession` functionality too. If you really wanted to restore all windows/tabs, by all means just use

```
:mksession! /tmp/tmpsession.vim
:# do the work
:source /tmp/tmpsession.vim
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  However, the :buffer command winds uploading that file in the last window.  Just like `Z was doing.

However, your mksession suggestion gave me an idea.  I'm testing it now...

Comment: @shaggyaxe if you set `switchbuf=useopen,usetab` you should get the window that already showed that buffer