# Jump to last cursor position after command in vim

Tags: vim

I have a user defined vim command which calls a vim-Skript:

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>)
```

if I execute it

```
:Shell echo "foo"
```

the cursor jumps to the first line of the file. But I want it to stay in the same place where it was before I entered the command.

I tried

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>) | ''
```

which does not seem to work.

The RunShellCommand is

```
" Shell command with output in vim scratch buffer
function! s:RunShellCommand(cmdline)
  let isfirst = 1
  let words = []
  for word in split(a:cmdline)
    if isfirst
      let isfirst = 0  " don't change first word (shell command)
    else
      if word[0] =~ '\v[%#<]'
        let word = expand(word)
      endif
      let word = shellescape(word, 1)
    endif
    call add(words, word)
  endfor
  let expanded_cmdline = join(words)
  botright new
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
  call setline(1, 'You entered:  ' . a:cmdline)
  call setline(2, 'Expanded to:  ' . expanded_cmdline)
  call append(line('$'), substitute(getline(2), '.', '=', 'g'))
  silent execute '$read !'. expanded_cmdline
    " close scratch buffer if successfull
    if v:shell_error == 0
        q
    endif
  1
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need "normal ``":

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>) | normal ``
```

Also see the winsaveview / winrestview functions described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9989348/85371

Comment: I tried this and command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell let saved_winnr = winnr() | call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>) | exec saved_winnr . 'wincmd w'
But neither seems to work. The RunShellCommand opens the scratch buffer and usually closes it again. In principle it should be as easy as adding a marker or saving the line number and returning to this position when the command is finished. But how  can I add a marker which does not overwrite possible user markers.

Comment: Where does RunShellCommand come from? I suspect this may be a feature of the plugin/script you are using, or otherwise, it would best be implemented as a (new) feature of it.

Comment: The RunShellCommand is a modified version of a vim script from vim tips, see edit.